# SUMIF Array Formula with merged columns + greater than date and less than date

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRgYl.png)

I need an array formula in L2 (column **Total Orders**) with results like on screenshot and that will

- sum **Orders** (Column E) of bunch of Color&Fruit&Meal in the range from **Start Date** (Column J) to **End Date** (Column K)

Is it possible to solve it with array formula?

I've tried but I don't know how to find any solution for this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(G2:G="","",SUMIF(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&A2:A&A2:A,G2:G&H2:H&I2:I&">="&J2:J&"<="&K2:K,E2:E)))
```

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-VyC54nhaa2AVAb6j-dla2lKbz_3tFKL7aWUle6tXTk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Thank you for sharing an editable sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will calculate the row-by-row Total Orders by the keys in columns `G:I` using the dates in columns `J` and `K` as filtering criteria:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isblank(G2:G), 
    iferror(1/0), 
    mmult( 
      ( 
        transpose(B2:B & C2:C & D2:D) 
        = 
        G2:G & H2:H & I2:I 
      ) 
      * 
      ( 
        (J2:J <= transpose(A2:A)) 
        * 
        (transpose(A2:A) <= K2:K) 
      ),
      n(E2:E) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula should go to cell `L2`.

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-VyC54nhaa2AVAb6j-dla2lKbz_3tFKL7aWUle6tXTk/edit#gid=756754981) sheet in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thnx but as i said, i need a formula for cell L2. Only for column L. And I want results in this column like in column L on screenshot/Google Sheets

Comment: so the whole question was how can i use here ARRAYFORMULA. I know about sumifs, but i don't want to drag the formula down

Comment: yes, that formula i have already in my question's description

Comment: Added explanation to the answer and prettified the formula.

Comment: @doubleunary Before you changed my solution, it was in cell L2 as requested by @MaxAmbinder. Here it is again for reference `=ArrayFormula(if(G2:G<>"",mmult({transpose(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D)=G2:G&H2:H&I2:I}*(transpose(A2:A)>=J2:J)*(transpose(A2:A)<=K2:K),N(E2:E)),))`

Comment: @Aresvik you are right, changed the formula back to L2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `query()` formula:

```
=query( 
  A1:E, 
  "select B, C, D, min(A), max(A), sum(E) 
   where A is not null 
   group by B, C, D 
   order by min(A)
   label min(A) 'Start Date', 
         max(A) 'End Date', 
         sum(E) 'Total Orders' ", 
  1 
)
```

This is an array formula that will create the whole result table in one go. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-VyC54nhaa2AVAb6j-dla2lKbz_3tFKL7aWUle6tXTk/edit#gid=0). The formula is in cell `G9`.

Comment: sorry, but no. i need an array formula for cell L2